Trouble adding a constraint based on an array of consecutive combinations of values with 'm.add_constr()', inside an optimization problem
i'm trying to solve an optimization problem by defining all the possible combinations of costs included in an array called values, to solve the problem. To do this, i used the following method:
for i in range(len(values)):
    for j in range(i+1, len(values)+1):
        result.append(values[i:j])

The resulting array will have "len(values) + (len(values)-1) + (...) + 1" rows and if printed will be visualized as:
[1]
[1, 2]
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
...
[1, 2, 3, 4, ..., len(values)]
...
[3]
[3, 4]
...
[3, 4, ..., len(values)]
etc...

I want to add a constraint to impose that the sum of the values contained in every group that I select from the array is lesser or equal than the thrshld I have set. Previously I initialized a binary array x[] with the same size of values. After using m.optimize(), the elements of x[] will be true if their index is the same as the last position in one of the combinations of values i have chosen as part of the optimal solution, and false otherwise...
To help me choose the right index of x[], I defined the following function:
def chooseindex(a, c, k):
  for j in range(a):
    c += a-j
    if k <= c:
      return j

in which a will be the length of the original array, c is the optional offset and k is the index of the element of result that is being considered
My solution was:
m.add_constr((sum(result[i])*(1 - x[len(result[i]) + chooseindex(len(values), 0, i) - 1]) for i in range(len(result)) <= (thrshld - 0.1))

The compiler returned the following error:
'<=' not supported between instances of 'generator' and 'float'

Afterwards I tried rearranging the terms as:
m.add_constr(sum(result[i])*(1 - x[len(result[i]) + chooseindex(len(values), 0, i) - 1])<= (thrshld - 0.1) for i in range(len(result))

but in return I got:
'generator' object has no attribute 'expr'

I also tried replacing thrshld with a list, but with no luck. Any suggestions on how to make this work?
